# How to properly ping and scan services on computer, then move on to next computer in list?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a list of a servers and services.  I can scan the servers for the list of services and get the status.  And I can separately ping the list of servers to see if they are up.

I am having trouble combining the 2.  I want to ping a server on the list, then scan that server for all services I have listed.  Display the status for all services.  Then move onto the next server in the list to do the same.

I just want to group them together so that the ping for the current server is displayed with the services scan for that server.

Any suggestions on how I can do this properly?

```
$serviceList = gc C:\services.txt

get-content C:\servers.txt | % {
ForEach ($service in $serviceList)
{




    if (Test-Connection -computer $_ -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet) {
        Write-Host $_ is online
    }
    else {"$_ is offline"}





    if ($s=get-service -computer $_ -name $service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        $s | select MachineName, ServiceName, Status, StartType
    }
    else {"$_ $service "}




    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Something like this works but the downed servers are displayed twice for some reason...

```
$serviceList = gc C:\services.txt   # gc is short for Get-Content



    get-content C:\servers.txt | % {
    ForEach ($service in $serviceList)
    {


        if (-not (Test-Connection -computer $_ -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)) {
            Write-Host "$_ is offline" -ForegroundColor Red
        }

        else {

        if ($s=get-service -computer $_ -name $service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        {
            $s | select MachineName, ServiceName, Status, StartType
        }
        else {"$_ $service "}

        }



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tidied up your code a bit because you're running `Test-Connection` for each **service** rather than for each server:

```
$serviceList = Get-Content C:\work\services.txt

Get-Content C:\work\servers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -EA 0 -Quiet) {
        foreach ($service in $serviceList) {
            if ($s=get-service -computer $_ -name $service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
            {
                $s | select MachineName, ServiceName, Status, StartType
            } else {
                "$_ $service "
            }
        }
    } else {
        "$_ is offline"
    }
}
```

but I don't think that's your fundamental issue.  I think the issue is that you're mixing up the way you're outputting data.  For example, what I wrote above gives:

```
MachineName  ServiceName  Status StartType
-----------  -----------  ------ ---------
bob1         RpcLocator  Stopped    Manual
bob1         SENS        Running Automatic
dave2 is offline
```

(which is the same order the machines appear in the server file).  You're using Write-Host in one place and (double-)quotes in another.  Using quotes is the equivalent of using Write-Output.  Write-Output sticks the data in the pipeline ready for the next cmdlet to process.  If there is no next cmdlet, the host formats the output for display.  This happens at the end of the script.

If I use Write-Host for the last `else`, the output becomes:

```
 dave2 is offline
 MachineName  ServiceName  Status StartType
 -----------  -----------  ------ ---------
 bob1         RpcLocator  Stopped    Manual
 bob1         SENS        Running Automatic
```

If I add `Write-Host "$_ is online"` between my `Test-Connection` and `foreach` lines, I get:

```
 bob1 is online
 dave2 is offline
 MachineName  ServiceName  Status StartType
 -----------  -----------  ------ ---------
 bob1         RpcLocator  Stopped    Manual
 bob1         SENS        Running Automatic
```

If you add Write-Host '-' at the end of your script, you'll see that the service data appear after that.

The simplest solution is to stick to using one output method.

Comment: Thank you.  That explains a lot.  I didn't know the difference between Write-Host and Write-Output.  My end goal is to also possibly dump this output into a file so I will probably use Write-Output.

Comment: You're welcome.  You might want to look at `Out-File` to write it to a file, or `Tee-Object` to write to both screen and file.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of the Tree-Object. Thanks